# ServiceStack logging and SSE in a single interface?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, servicestack, log4net

So, our project has recently started using Server Sent Events in ServiceStack.  Our projects also log with log4net, using the log4net provider.  Now that I've gotten through a couple of components using SSE, I am wondering if anyone else is thinking what I am here...

I typically use the 'DEBUG' level of log4net for a real chatty, 'debug' experience.  When I'm on dev servers, or when I'm trying to get to the bottom of an issue... I'll change the logging level to 'DEBUG' and go to town.  While I wouldn't run in higher environments using 'DEBUG' - I find that same level of information is what I might be interested in sending to a client.  I have some long-running processes in a service, and it communicates with the web dashboard via SSE to report updates.  I'm finding that the type of information that I would typically log to 'DEBUG' is *generally* what I would like to send to my dashboard.  As you can then imagine, my code starts to look like this, and in many areas:

```
var msg = $"Processed {count} records.";
MessageLog.Debug(msg);
ServerEvents.NotifyChannel(channelName, selector, msg);
```

Seeing this makes me want to create a thin wrapper to enable the message to be sent to either the log, the SSE, or both with a single call.  Does this type of setup exist in ServiceStack at present?  I realize it's high level and there's details to work out (logging level, channel and selector values) but I have to believe there is some way to simplify this.

Comment: I've been tooling around with the idea of a debug/admin dashboard for SS, and I think this would be perfect.  Select the level of logging & have it populate in the Plugin's web page.  Other ideas include traffic analysis by request, registered plugins, active sessions (from cache provider), etc.

Comment: @jklemmack - I should have been more clear in my post - the ServiceStack project that I'm asking about here is a running Windows service.  The web dashboard I mentioned that it is communicating with is a node.js project, using TypeScript.  But I agree, I've played with this too, having requests and log4net logs queried using AutoQuery... it was pretty easy to wire up, just didn't have it on a dedicated page or anything.  We just used the standard AutoQuery admin page for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything built-in, there are a couple ways you could implement this, my preference would be to use an extension method which takes an `ILog`, e.g:

```
public static void NotifyChannel(this IServerEvents server, 
    string channel, string selector, object message, ILog log)
{
    if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
        log.Debug(message);

    server.NotifyChannel(channel, selector, message);
}
```

Or you could create an adapter `IServerEvents` class that you can register as a separate dependency, e.g:

```
container.Register(c => 
    new LoggingServerEvents(c.Resolve<IServerEvents>()));
```

Which logs and delegates API calls to the `IServerEvents` dependency, e.g:

```
class LoggingServerEvents : IServerEvents
{
    private static ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LoggingServerEvents));

    private IServerEvents sse;
    public LoggingServerEvents(IServerEvents sse) => this.sse = sse;

    public void NotifyChannel(string channel, string selector, object message)
    {
        if (Log.IsDebugEnabled)
            Log.Debug(message);

        sse.NotifyChannel(channelName, selector, message);
    }

    //...
}
```

Which you can reference in your Services like a normal dependency that you can use instead of `ServerEvents` when you want the message to also be logged, e.g:

```
public class MyServices : Service
{
    public LoggingServerEvents LoggingServerEvents { get; set; }

    public object Any(MyRequest request)
    {
        //ServerEvents.NotifyChannel(channelName, selector, msg);
        LoggingServerEvents.NotifyChannel(channelName, selector, msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: two clever ideas here, I'll give it a whirl.  I wasn't sure if I was missing something in the framework, always like to ask before I set out to create something here.  appreciate your response - thanks!